# get the root parent node using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've imported a csv file to neo4j and created nodes and relationships for them.

In the above the first two nodes comes under db1 and last four nodes comes under db2.
How to find that last four nodes belongs to db2?

Below is the code and csv file
columnname,tablename,databasename,systemname
abc,1a,db1,Finance
def,1a,db1,Finance
ghi,1a,db1,Finance
klm,1a,db1,Finance
abc,1a,db2,Medical
def,1a,db2,Medical
ghi,1a,db2,Medical
klm,1a,db2,Medical
nop,1a,db2,Medical
qrs,1a,db2,Medical

```
I've created nodes and relationships for the above csv file in neo4j
This is for getting unique values   
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:ColumnName) ASSERT c.ColumnName IS UNIQUE;
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:TableName) ASSERT c.TableName IS UNIQUE;
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:DatabaseName) ASSERT c.DatabaseName IS UNIQUE;
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:SystemName) ASSERT c.SystemName IS UNIQUE;

This is for loading csv file and creating nodes and relationships

    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS line
    MERGE (ColumnName:ColumnName {ColumnName: line.ColumnName})
    MERGE (TableName:TableName {TableName:line.TableName})
    MERGE (DatabaseName: DatabaseName {DatabaseName:line.DatabaseName})
    MERGE (SystemName: SystemName {SystemName:line.SystemName})

This is creating relationships among the nodes
     MERGE (ColumnName)-[:iscolumnof]->(TableName)
     MERGE (TableName)-[:istableof]->(DatabaseName)
     MERGE (DatabaseName)-[:isdatabaseof ]->(SystemName)
     
 If, i select one node 'nop'and expand i'll get the node(1a) 1a and if i expand 1a i'll get all the 
nodes(columns). How to find that 'nop' belongs to 'db2'?
```

[image: csv file]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have a pattern

```
(:ColumnName)-[:iscolumnof]->(:TableName)-[:istableof]->(:DatabaseName)-[:isdatabaseof ]->(:SystemName)
```

If you want to test whether a certain :ColumnName belongs to a :DatabaseName

```
WITH 'nop' AS columnName, 'db2' AS databaseName
MATCH (col:ColumnName {ColumnName:columnName}),(db:DatabaseName 
{DatabaseName:databaseName})
RETURN EXISTS((col)-[:iscolumnof]->(:TableName)-[:istableof]->(db)) AS result
```

If you want all the columns of db2

```
WITH 'db2' AS databaseName
MATCH (c:ColumnName)-[:iscolumnof]->(:TableName)-[:istableof]->(:DatabaseName {DatabaseName:databaseName}) 
RETURN c.ColumnName AS column
```

Comment: Thankyou.

WITH 'nop' AS columnName, 'db2' AS databaseName
RETURN EXISTS((:ColumnName {ColumnName:columnName})-[:iscolumnof]->(:TableName)-[:istableof]->(:DatabaseName {DatabaseName:databaseName}))  AS result

For this i'm getting error as "Index 2 out of bounds for length 0"

Comment: Improved the cypher a bit, but it probably does not solve your secondary issue. don't know why .. if I run the cypher with an  'explain' prefix, it does not return an error

Comment: WITH 'db2' AS databaseName
MATCH (c:ColumnName)-[:iscolumnof]->(:TableName)-[:istableof]->(:DatabaseName {DatabaseName:databaseName}) 
RETURN c.ColumnName AS column

The output returns a table. Can we visualize this as graph instead of table?

Comment: Yes, if you use ( t:Tablename) and RETURN c,t,DatabaseName

Comment: @Ravali yw, looking forward to you accepting the answer then. ;-)